# PowerShell open, save and close files with same filename at network storage

Tags: excel, powershell, foreach

I already made few steps forward..

On opening, saving and closing specified excel file at network directory.

```
$dir="\\10.100.0.10\folder\user.name\2015\file.xlsx"
$excl=New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
$wrkb=$excl.Workbooks.Open($dir)
$excl.DisplayAlerts = $FALSE
$wrkb.Save()
$wrkb.Close()
$excl.Quit()
```

How can i insert loop so it could search files with same filename

> file.xlsx

at this shared location thru all users *for example*

> \\10.100.0.10\folder\

Finding file, opening it saving and closing?

Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First search the `\\10.100.0.0\folder` (and subfolders) for files with the name `file.xlsx`

Add the FullPath of each file found to a variable `($Files)`

Use `foreach` to add each file and process it, like this:

```
$Files = Dir '\\10.100.0.10\folder' -Recurse | ? {$_.Name -eq "file.xlsx"} | Select -ExpandProperty FullName
$excl=New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
foreach ($file in $Files)
{
$wrkb=$excl.Workbooks.Open($file)
$excl.DisplayAlerts = $FALSE
$wrkb.Save()
$wrkb.Close()
}
$excl.Quit()
```

Comment: Functional, but could be better. You should always have the provider filter when able (much faster). Also, you need to expand the property, not just select it. So `$Files = Get-ChildItem '\\10.100.0.10\folder\file.xlsx' -Recurse | Select -Expand FullName` will find all files with the name "file.xlsx" within \\10.100.0.10\folder and all sub folders as well, and will store the FullName (entire path to the file, including file name) property of each file found as an array of strings in the `$Files` variable.

Comment: Also, what you use is fine for saving and closing, but you can also just do `$wrkb.Close($true)` and skip saving before it. That won't help speed up the script I don't think, but it might. You canalso  move the DisplayAlerts line outside of the loop.